# Overriding disabling of Firefox's "allow pages to choose their own fonts" in CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

I'm using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) for my icons in [Peer.fm](http://peer.fm/), and I've recently received a bug report from a user that the icons don't display properly in Firefox when the "allow pages to choose their own fonts" setting is disabled.

Short of actually converting my icons to images, is there any way to override that browser setting on my end in this specific case?

Comment: I understand your reasons but, if it was possible for you, it'd be possible for anyone, thus the feature would be useless.

Comment: Frankly, that's unarguably user error. I don't know if disabling fonts is a per-domain setting in Firefox -- if it isn't, tell the user to file it as a feature request with Mozilla. On the other hand, if you use semantically useful positions in unicode, you'll degrade somewhat gracefully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This setting affects how the browser processes a site's CSS, and your page has no power to change that.

[This thread on the Mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/947228) discusses your issue. An official response:

> This looks that some custom font is used for those icons, so it is only possible to check this on a real page.
>   Such a font is specified and downloaded on the web page via an @font-face rule and such fonts are only applied if fonts from the server are enabled....
>   There is nothing to do about this other than (temporarily) enable website fonts on those pages.

Workarounds, such as downloading the custom font and setting it as the browser's default, are possible, but can only be applied locally by the user.